How to set a phantom box in tcolorbox?
I am trying to create a phantombox (i.e., a box whose contents and size are exactly the same as they are if its contents were not inside tcolorbox environment). If I combine two contents to check, I find that contents are not aligned (I aligned them using an external software)

My MWE
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sampleText}{}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adip- iscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent im- perdiet mi nec ante.}

\tcbset{PhantomFrame/.style=
    {
        % outer spacing
        before=\vspace*{\parskip}, after=, 
        % inner spacings
        top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
        left=0pt, right=0pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        % corners
        arc=0pt,
        % growing to left and right
        grow to left by=0pt, grow to right by=0pt,
        % rules
        boxrule=0pt,
        % colors
        colback=Ivory1,
        % opacity
        opacityframe=0, opacityback=1,
    }
}

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\begin{tcolorbox}[PhantomFrame]
    
    \sampleText
    
\end{tcolorbox}

Text

\hrule

\bigskip

\hrule

\sampleText

Text

\hrule

\end{document}


You can try something like
beforeafter skip balanced=\parskip,
before upper=\strut,
after upper=\strut,

If you need many paragraphs inside the tcolorbox, you can add parbox=false to get the formatting of the main text (but the manual says that it has some unwanted side effects; it is maybe preferable to reset \parskip and \parindent).
Note also that size=minimal set all spaces and rules width to zero, and that you're setting grow to left by, grow to right by and opacityback to their default values. The PhantomFrame style can therefor be defined by
\tcbset{PhantomFrame/.style=
    {
      beforeafter skip balanced=\parskip,
      before upper=\strut,
      after upper=\strut,
      size=minimal,
      colback=Ivory1,
      parbox=false,
    }
}

Anyway, I'm not sure it works in all circumstances.
Example :
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\sampleText}{}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  adip- iscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque
  pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent im- perdiet mi nec ante.}

\tcbset{PhantomFrame/.style=
    {
      beforeafter skip balanced=\parskip,
      before upper=\strut,
      after upper=\strut,
      size=minimal,
      colback=Ivory1,
      parbox=false,
    }
}


\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\hrule

\begin{tcolorbox}[PhantomFrame]
    \sampleText
\end{tcolorbox}

Text

\hrule

\bigskip

\hrule

\sampleText

Text

\hrule

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

Text

\sampleText

\sampleText

Text

\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

Text

\begin{tcolorbox}[PhantomFrame]
\sampleText

\sampleText
\end{tcolorbox}

Text

\end{minipage}

\end{document}



The distance to "Text" is a bit different https://i.sstatic.net/fzL1c446.gif

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Argh! You right.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I edited my answer. I hope it works now.
